# Wrong SVG files are rendered in document

Tags: floats, minipage, svg

I am trying to display two figures, which both contain two SVG images in separate minipages each:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1.0\textwidth]{plots/PrisonersDilemma/Lattice2D/initial_moral_mean_stability}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1.0\textwidth]{plots/PrisonersDilemma/Lattice2D/initial_moral_mean_morality}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \caption{Figure 1}
    \label{fig:label1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1.0\textwidth]{plots/StagHunt/Lattice2D/initial_moral_mean_stability}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includesvg[width=1.0\textwidth]{plots/StagHunt/Lattice2D/initial_moral_mean_morality}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \caption{Figure 2}
    \label{fig:label2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In the output, the latter two images are rendered as the first two. That is, the two SVGs in the second figure are supposed to be different:

[image]

The SVG files are at the exact locations specified, and I made sure that all four are different. It seems like LaTeX is using the files specified in the first figure for the second figure, too. What am I doing wrong here?

[Download archive containing both .tex file and the SVG files for reproducing](https://ufile.io/9akysf6i)

Comment: It may be erroneous caching because the filenames are the same (although on different paths). You could try to give the files different names and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, this is due to the identical file names. By default, all generated files are stored in the current working folder under `.\svg-inkscape` by their simple file name, which is why these files are overwritten (there are only two pdf files under `.\svg-inkscape`). This issue (https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/11) is already known, I am going to fix it in the next main release. For now, `\svgsetup{inkscapepath=svgsubdir}` could be used as a workaround. This will place the generated files in the respective subfolder of the svg file.

Comment: `\svgsetup{inkscapepath=svgsubdir}` does indeed solve the problem. Thank you!